# How to create multiple Divs in Pug/Jade and use the for Loop value(x)?

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I'm trying to create multiple divs in pug this is the code I have:

```
- for(var x = 0;x < 3;x++)
.background-line.line-x
```

How do I use the variable "x"?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is setup correct, but you need to follow indentations rules for PUG.

The line `.background-line.line-x` has to be nested under your `for` loop. You can see in the pen below:

https://codepen.io/mdiggss/pen/eGaEBO

As for the variable `x`, this is used as your counter for the `for` loop and it will iterate as long as `x` is `< 3` - Your sample will produce 3 divs each with the classes you specified.

Comment: true, but how to use the x value? I'm trying to create .line-1 .line-2 and etc using "x"

Comment: @Harp I've updated the pen. You need to specify that you are creating a `div` along with the class name(s) and then use interpolation to specify that you want to use the iterator

Comment: @Harp no problem - if this resolved your issue, don't forget to mark as complete ;)